# what runs the subscribed report in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services

so my question is, what runs the subscribed report in SSRS ? I mean when I subscribe to report and give it a desired time when it should run and send me the file. something does this right ? so I want to know what runs it ? is it a procedure in SQL function ? well the reason why I want to know this is that I want to run SQL update before each time this scheduled report starts.

I can just create procedure that will do the update I want before the scheduled time but, still it will be more practical to integrate it within the job itself

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, these subscriptions are run as database jobs through the **SQL Server Agent**.

They are created with GUID type names:

[image]

The one job step will have a command like:

```
exec [ReportServer].dbo.AddEvent @EventType='SharedSchedule', @EventData='8df4ff30-97d3-41f7-b3ef-9ce48bfdfbfa'
```

You can trace these jobs/GUIDs back to the subscription and report through the **ReportServer** database using the `Subscriptions` table and its `MatchData` column (matches the job GUID) and the `Catalog` table which includes the report data (i.e. linked through the `Subscriptions.Report_OID` column.

You can use this information to check what's scheduled and based on this schedule your update appropriately.

I haven't tried it myself, but one option could even be to hook into the existing database jobs, but I would approach this with caution; I can't see any issues but maybe it's best not to update any system created jobs like these.

Comment: Was this solution any help to you?